# Run javascript code only in publish page not in edit

Tags: javascript, publishing-page

I am running some javascript code in on page but I don't want it running when I try and edit the page. How can I stop this from running in edit page and only when the page has been published

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for MSOLayout_InDesignMode

```
var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

if (inDesignMode == "1")
{
    // page is in edit mode
}
else
{
    // page is in browse mode
}
```

This will refer to value of the following html input control, which is rendering on the page when it is in edit mode:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MSOLayout_InDesignMode" id="MSOLayout_InDesignMode" value="1" />
```

For wiki pages, you will need _wikiPageMode parameter:

```
var wikiInEditMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value;
if (wikiInEditMode == "Edit")
{
    // wiki page is in edit mode
}
else
{
    // wiki page is not in edit mode
}
```